# Something like MS Access, but in the cloud

Tags: database, ms-access, web-applications, web

Forgive a simple question. Is there a product like MS Access, which can be placed on a hosted web server, which runs simple database systems with straightforward UIs.

The reason I want it on a web server is so that it can be accesses by remote staff. The reason I want straightforward UIs (with basic screens and modals etc. taken care of) is to speed up development time, to concentrate on functionality.

Comment: Sorry, I should mention I have not budget whatsoever except hosting, and I need an IDE that works on a MAC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible consideration is to continue to use access.  Access 2010 now has web publishing, and you can publish Access applications to office 365 or SharePoint.

The great thing about this system is Access Web Services retains and keeps the rapid application development paradigm that Access is so famous for.

You don't have VBA in web forms, but all the classic features such as continuous forms, sub forms, and opening forms with a where clause to filter form all exist in the new macro programming language.

Take a look of the following video of mine running where I built a room booking application built with Access 2010. Notice how at the halfway Point I switch to run in the application 100% inside of a web browser:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AU4mH0jPntI

Keep in mind the above applications do not require silver light, nor do they require any ActiveX or download of components to be installed on the target machine.  As a result of these applications from fine on an apple iPad, or on my smart phone. So even Firefox or Safari web browsers can consume these applications.

The new access web publishing feature requires that you have either SharePoint 2010 (enterprise edition), or you consider some type of hosting such as www.acccesshosting.com.

Another choice (and the most low cost) is to consider using office 365. The Office 365 P1 plan starts at $6 per month and supports what is called Access Web Services. You can invite up to 50 users to that site to utilize your application for that single low $6 per month price.

The only downside to using office 365 p1 plan is this low cost cloud computing option is that Access web reports are not currently supported. You can however connect the client (Access desktop edition) to the data up in the cloud and run reports that way.

Note that if you choose something like www.accesshosting.com or you have SharePoint services, then Access web reports are supported.

So if you're looking for something like Access that allows you to publish to the web perhaps you actually use Access!

Answer (score 1):

Oracle Application Express does what you want... it can even import from MS Access.  Oracle APEX can run on [Oracle Express](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/express-edition/overview/index.html) (and thus is free).  No IDE is needed--though you might want to use something for javascript or use Oracle SqlDeveloper (Java based).

Comment: Can you deploy this on any average joe webserver or do you need something highly dedicated for it?

Comment: It uses Oracle Application Server.  Oracle XE includes Application Express

Comment: Is there anything you have to pay for?

Comment: It depends on your requirements.  XE is single user setup.  I suggest looking at the Oracle website.